# React Async post method all working after the button is clicked a second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

I have a checkout page that post the form and the cart information to the database and it should return a response.

This is the handle submit code:

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    const { selectedDate: selectedCakeDate, selectedTime: selectedCakeTime } =
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cake-date-and-time'));

    const {
      selectedDate: selectedNonCakeDate,
      selectedTime: selectedNonCakeTime,
    } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('non-cake-date-and-time'));

    setTotal(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('total-price')));
    setDatesAndTimes({
      nonCake: {
        selectedDate: selectedNonCakeDate,
        selectedTime: selectedNonCakeTime,
      },
      cake: {
        selectedDate: selectedCakeDate,
        selectedTime: selectedCakeTime,
      },
    });

    let id;

    const information = {
      id: id,
      firstName: userData.firstName,
      lastName: userData.lastName,
      email: userData.email,
      countryCode: userData.countryCode,
      number: userData.number,
      residence: userData.residence,
      service,
      paymentMethod,
      items: cart,
      total,
      datesAndTimes,
    };

    if (user && userInformation) {
      information.id = userInformation.id;
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/orders', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ information }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      });

      const json = await response.json();

      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(json.Message);
        return;
      }

      setIsButtonClicked(true);
      localStorage.removeItem('cart');
      localStorage.removeItem('total-price');
      localStorage.removeItem('cake-date-and-time');
      localStorage.removeItem('non-cake-date-and-time');
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_CART_SIZE', payload: '0' });
      navigate('/');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Here is the form:

```html
<form
        className="checkout-content-container"
        onSubmit={event => handleSubmit(event)}
      >
        <p className="checkout-header">Checkout</p>
        <Information
          user={user}
          userInformation={userInformation}
          isLoading={isLoading}
          onFormChange={handleUserInfoCollection}
        />
        <span className="divider"></span>
        <Service onButtonClick={handleServiceCollection} />
        <span className="divider"></span>
        <Payment onButtonClick={handlePaymentMethodCollection} />
        <span className="divider"></span>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className={!isButtonClicked ? 'place-order' : 'order-placed'}
          disabled={isButtonClicked}
        >
          {!isButtonClicked ? (
            'Place order'
          ) : (
            <div
              style={{
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
              Order placed
              <span className="material-symbols-outlined">done</span>
            </div>
          )}
        </button>
      </form>
```

So when I click the button the first nothing happens in the console of the server I get this `api/orders POST` and when it goes through I get `POST api/orders 200` which is when it works, then the button change text and it loads up the home page just as it should.

I figured it was due to the nature of the async and I cannot seem to put my finger on the issue.